# Excel VBA : looping around rows, then referencing a cell in that row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to loop around cells containing data within a particular sheet, then print each cell in that row to a file.

This is the code I have, but the syntax of the print row is erroring. I don't see what this issue is. I am trying to print out what is in column A for each row containing data.

```
Private Sub GENERATE_ORDER_BUTTON_Click()

    Dim path As String
    path = "H:\order.json"

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set A = fs.createtextfile(path, True)
    A.WriteLine ("{")
    A.Close
    
    Dim outputstring As String
    outputstring = "  ""BASE_CE"": ["
    
    Open path For Append As #1
    Print #1, outputstring
    Close #1
    
    
    Dim LastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("CE Router")

    LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set RowRange = ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    
    For Each rrow In RowRange
    
        Set ws = Sheets("CE Router")
        
        Open path For Append As #1
        Print #1, "    {"
        Print #1, ws.Range("A" & rrow).Value
        Close #1
    
    Next rrow

 
End Sub
```

Comment: `rrow` should be a cell range, so try `rrow.Row` in the erroring line. You usually do e.g. this `For Each rrow In RowRange.Cells`, or  this `For Each rrow In RowRange.Rows` when it becomes clear that `rrow` refers to a range.

Comment: This is working thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### Using File System Object to Write to Text File

- FYI `VBE>Tools>References>Microsoft Scripting Runtime` is the same library the `Dictionary` object uses which could help you to make this more efficiently.

**Learning Mode**

```
Option Explicit

Sub orderButton()
    Const FilePath = "F:\Test\2020\65234018\order.json"
    ' Create a reference to  VBE>Tools>References>Microsoft Scripting Runtime.
    ' Now you have intellisense for File System Object, so you can learn.
    Dim fs As Scripting.FileSystemObject: Set fs = New FileSystemObject
    fs.CreateTextFile FilePath, True
    Dim tFile As File: Set tFile = fs.GetFile(FilePath)
    Dim tStream As TextStream: Set tStream = tFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting)
    With tStream
        ' 1.
        .WriteLine ("{")
        .WriteLine "  ""BASE_CE"": ["
        ' 2.
        Dim ColumnRange As Range
        Dim cel As Range
        Dim LastRow As Long
        ' If other workbook than the one containing this code,
        ' then use its name or 'ActiveWorkbook'.
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("CE Router")
            LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set ColumnRange = .Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
        End With
        For Each cel In ColumnRange.Cells
            .WriteLine "    {"
            .WriteLine cel.Value
        Next cel
        .Close
    End With

End Sub
```

**Later**

```
' When you have learned you can use the following without variables
' and without a reference (wouldn't recommend it for now):
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    .CreateTextFile FilePath, True
    With .GetFile(FilePath).OpenAsTextStream(ForWriting)
        ' The code
    End with
End With
```